# how use application name replace ip:port about spring cloud eureka?

Tags: spring-cloud, netflix-eureka, spring-cloud-netflix

spring cloud eureka question: there are 3 microservices, 1 eureka server, 2 eureka client;

1. microservice A,B use annotation `@EnableEurekaClient`;
2. microservice A have a RESTful api "http://localhost:8080/hi". the api return "hello".
3. now, I call the api , use url "http://client/hi", but it doesn't work.
4. how use application name replace ip:port  about spring cloud eureka?

the **bootstrap.yml** content:

```
spring:
  application:
    name: client

eureka:
  client:
    service-url:
      defaultZone: http://${eureka.host:localhost}:${eureka.port:8761}/eureka/
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do that and it depends on how you call REST API in your code.

If you are using `RestTemplate` to call the API, you can do that with `@LoadBalanced RestTemplate`

In your code that wants to invoke REST api, please define `RestTemplate` with `@LoadBalanced` like below.

```
@LoadBalanced
@Bean
RestTemplate restTemplate(){
  return new RestTemplate();
}
```

And when you call API, just use application name instead of `host:port` like below.

```
this.restTemplate.getForObject("http://client/hi", String.class)
```

If you are using SpringCloud Feign, you can define the interface to call your REST api like below (without URL)

```
@FeignClient(name="client")
public interface ProductResource {
   : 
}
```

And add annotation `@EnableFeignClients` in your spring boot application like below.

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
     : // other annotations you need.
public class YourAPIInvokerApplication {
```

In both ways, you need to add a few dependencies.

Comment: I am using feign but it isn't working this way

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `RestTemplate`, but i got `Connection timed out: connect` after put serviceName instead of `localhost:port`

```
@Bean
@LoadBalanced
public RestTemplate restTemplate() {
    return new RestTemplate();
}
```

call API:

```
FraudCheckResponse fraudCheckResponse = customerConfig.restTemplate().getForObject(
            "http://fraud/api/v1/fraud-check/{customerId}",
            FraudCheckResponse.class,
            customer.getId()
    );
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).